# Html form: Select multiple, only one value is submitted

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

from the spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fuQK9VYk_rV9bO8DvL7iBHiupBtDmbqrv-GV-dirRTk/edit?usp=sharing

I created the html form

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzIKY4rg0Fp5wvaqov5SIK9_je4aJn4tqY9lsbwKCtLropgSrw/exec

The problem is when I choose more than one option, only one option (the first selected one) is submitted to the sheet

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
</style>

<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" id="form" action="script URL" method="POST">

<select name="Options" id="Options" aria-required="true" required="" size="4" multiple="multiple">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
<option value="option5">option5</option>
<option value="option6">option6</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the input name into this `name="Options[]"` but it gives undefined in the sheet

.gs

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html')
        .evaluate()
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Show your `doPost()` receiver

Comment: The .gs is added to the question. Thanks

Comment: I agree with the below answer. However, try `e.parameters[header]`(that's parameter`s`) instead first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the post values you need to use `e.postData.contents` instead of `e.parameter` which will only return you one value per field/parameter [1]:

> Only the first value is returned for parameters that have multiple
>   values.

A much better way (easier ans secure) to work with forms and send data to the server is working with `withSuccessHandler` function [2] instead of using the action attribute on form element.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: If it helped you please consider accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I'm still working on it but of course you helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding `var Options = e.postData.contents.Options;` to the .gs file code (mentioned above in the question) but still posting only the first selected value to the sheet. Any ideas